# passing parameter in the url - nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http

I have a problem in nodejs, see if any one could help me out.

I have a page.html to which I need to pass a param with value like

```
page.html?s=1
```

I am not able to send it, when I send it I am taken to a blank page.

server.js looks like the following:

```
var app = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var url = require('url') ;

var http = app.createServer(function handler(request, response) {

var filePath = '.' + request.url;
if (filePath == './')
    filePath = './index.html';

var extname = path.extname(filePath);
var contentType = 'text/html';
switch (extname) {
    case '.js':
        contentType = 'text/javascript';
        break;
    case '.css':
        contentType = 'text/css';
        break;
    case '.json':
        contentType = 'application/json';
        break;
    case '.png':
        contentType = 'image/png';
        break;
    case '.jpg':
        contentType = 'image/jpg';
        break;
    case '.wav':
        contentType = 'audio/wav';
        break;
    case '.xml':
        contentType = 'text/xml';
        break;
}

fs.readFile(filePath, function (error, content) {
    if (error) {
        if (error.code == 'ENOENT') {
            fs.readFile('./404.html', function (error, content) {
                response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': contentType});
                response.end(content, 'utf-8');
            });
        }
        else {
            response.writeHead(500);
            response.end('Sorry, check with the site admin for error: ' + error.code + ' ..\n');
            response.end();
        }
    }
    else {
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': contentType});
        response.end(content, 'utf-8');
    }
});

}).listen(3100);
console.log('Server started at 3100');
```

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: And the HTTP/200 is the return code ... ? Maybe some log from the server? Who does the split of "filename?s=1" into query part s=1 and filename (I am not a node.js practitioner, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

What you doing is called query strings, a `url parameter` would be  `page.html/:something`

Comment: Tried, that did not work for me on node js. Can you provide some links thats supports your answer ?